# TwebBrowser Delphi - как сделать аналог F5

Tags: delphi, webbrowser

Недавно заметил неприятную особенность. Когда в TWebBrowser прописываешь:  `WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:'+ '[тут HTML код]');`
То повторный вызов `WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:'+ '[тут HTML код]');`  обновляет содержимое  WebBrowser1 и всё нормально.
Но вот если написать:
`WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://domenname.ru/script.php');`
то WebBrowser1 не обновляет динамически меняющиеся контент из php, пока в настоящем браузере IE не нажмёшь F5 или правой кнопкой и по контекстному "Обновить".
Также заметил, что если даже подсовывать `WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:'+...`, а потом снова `WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://domenname.ru/script.php');`, то всё равно он не обновит содержимое, т.е. он берёт содержимое из своего центрального кэша IE.
Как устранить этот недочёт?
P.S. Может в него VK_F5 как-то послать? Но не получается:
`PostMessage(Form1.WebBrowser1.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0);` не срабатывает
`SendMessage(Form1.WebBrowser3.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0);` тоже не срабатывает.
Как быть прям не знаю, вся жизнь коту под хвост.

Comment: Чисто догадки, интерфейс досконально не помню, но можно попробовать через js пробить его. 1)Попробуйте `WebBrowser1.Navigate('javascript:location.reload(true);')` 2)Возможно там где-то в document валяется ф-ция refresh - точно не помню как вызвать.

Comment: А еще можно вызывать адрес добавкой в конце знака попроса+цифры "?88484", цифры все время другие ставь. В этом случае принудительно перезапрашивается документ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выход и положения подсказала [вот эта заметка](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/click_clear_cache_btn_in_ie.html) - чистка кэша IE программным путём.
Реализация:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var

  lpEntryInfo : PInternetCacheEntryInfo;
  hCacheDir : LongWord;
  dwEntrySize : LongWord;
  dwLastError : LongWord;

begin

  dwEntrySize := 0;
  FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(nil, TInternetCacheEntryInfo(nil^ ), dwEntrySize);
  GetMem(lpEntryInfo, dwEntrySize);
  hCacheDir := FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(nil, lpEntryInfo^, dwEntrySize);
  if (hCacheDir <> 0) then
    DeleteUrlCacheEntry(lpEntryInfo^.lpszSourceUrlName);
  FreeMem(lpEntryInfo);
  repeat
    dwEntrySize := 0;
    FindNextUrlCacheEntry(hCacheDir, TInternetCacheEntryInfo(nil^ ), dwEntrySize);
    dwLastError := GetLastError;
    if (GetLastError = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) then
    begin
      GetMem(lpEntryInfo, dwEntrySize);
      if (FindNextUrlCacheEntry(hCacheDir, lpEntryInfo^, dwEntrySize))     then
        DeleteUrlCacheEntry(lpEntryInfo^.lpszSourceUrlName);
      FreeMem(lpEntryInfo);
    end;
  until
    (dwLastError = ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS);

  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://domenname.ru/script.php');

end;
```

Всё заобновлялось, всё заработало.

Comment: А чем не угодил метод `TWebBrowser.Refresh` или `Refresh2`? Чистить кеш всего IE - ну, это как-то слишком...

Comment: @kami, а вы на практике попробуйте. Создайте php, меняйте его динамически от условий и посмотрите, как будет ваш `TWebBrowser.Refresh` срабатывать на это...